# Examples of local fields

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, absolute-convergence, local-field

A local field is a field that is locally compact and complete w.r.t. absolute value.

Does there exist a local field $K$ which is compact?

Comment: If $\lvert x\rvert > 1$, can $(x^n)$ have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Does there must exist some $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert > 1$? Can we have $\lvert x\rvert \leq 1$  for all x?

Comment: Note that $|xy|=|x|\,|y|$, and $|1|=1$

Comment: @math112358 A local field has, by definition, a nontrivial valuation, so some nonzero element has $|x|\neq 1$. If $|x|<1$, then $|x^{-1}|>1$.

Comment: I can show that $|x^n|$ has no convergent subsequencd, but how to show that  $(x^n)$ has no convergent subseqeunce.

Comment: @Wojowu，how to conclude that $(x^n)s has no convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a unital associative ring, endowed with a topological ring topology (say, addition and multiplication are continuous). If $R$ is compact then the set of left invertible elements in $R$ is closed (indeed, it is the first projection of the closed subset $\{(x,y):xy=1\}$. In particular, if $R\neq\{0_R\}$, then $0_R$ does not belong to the closure of the set of left-invertible elements. In particular, the only (Hausdorff) compact topological fields (or skew-fields) are finite.

Comment: Does there exist a finite local field ?

Comment: With your definition yes. But usually one explicitly requires local fields to be non-discrete.